# Fetch JSON data from Sencha ExtJS4 tree

Tags: json, extjs

I have a treestore which feed a tree in my form.
I want to change the structure of the tree and to post the entire new tree JSON encoded to server?
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure a proxy on the model of the treeStore. You add the right api urls (for read, create, update, destroy). Now you can call save on the model or sync on the store.

Not shure but I think you can put a proxy on the treeStore too...

Here you can find detailed info about [treestores](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/tree)